# Can I use bwboundaries and regionprops together on a labelmap?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using MATLAB to create a struct with "objects"/"regions" that can be seen in a labeled image. I am extracting the properties **BoundingBox** and **Area** with [`regionprops`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html). Since it unfortunately (and to me surprisingly) cannot extract the **boundary** (a list of pixels delineating the region) I'm creating those with [`bwboundary`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html)). This poses a problem though:

`obj = regionprops(obj_labelmap,'BoundingBox','Area','PixelIdxList');` gives a Nx1 struct with N regions, where the n-th region corresponds to the label n (e.g. `obj(1)` corresponds to the region labeled with 1).

`obj_boundaries = bwboundaries(obj_labelmap, 'noholes');` I'd expect to work in the same way. It almost does, but only for about 80% of the labels. It arbitrarily mixes some labels up, so that `obj_boundaries(1)` may correspond to the region labeled with 5 (or any other).

The problem is illustrated below, where one label is the regionprops (BoundingBox) index and the other the obj_boundaries (boundary) index. The figure was generated using this code on the labelmap that I uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d83l40s10v0ry5x/labelmap.mat?dl=0):

```
% get obj regions and boundaries from labelmap
obj_all = regionprops(obj_labelmap,'BoundingBox','Area','PixelIdxList');
obj_boundaries = bwboundaries(obj_labelmap, 'noholes');

imshow(obj_labelmap ~= 0); hold on;     % background image
colors=['b' 'g' 'r' 'c' 'm' 'y'];
for k=1:length(obj_boundaries),

    boundary = obj_boundaries{k};       % get boundary
    cidx = mod(k,length(colors))+1;     % set color
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1),...
        colors(cidx),'LineWidth',1);

    % plot text for boundary
    % randomize text position for better visibility
    rndRow = ceil(length(boundary)/(mod(rand*k,7)+1));
    col = boundary(rndRow,2); row = boundary(rndRow,1);
    h = text(col+1, row-1, [num2str(k)]);% '|' num2str(obj_labelmap(row,col))]);
    set(h,'Color',colors(cidx),'FontSize',10,'FontWeight','bold');

    % plot bounding boxes
    bb = obj_all(k).BoundingBox;
    rectangle('Position', bb,...
        'EdgeColor', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'LineWidth', 1)

    % plot text
    col = bb(1) ; row = bb(2);
    h = text(col+3, row+3, num2str(k));
    set(h,'Color',colors(cidx),'FontSize',10,'FontWeight','bold');
end
```

[image: differently assigned labels]

When trying to merge the boundaries into the struct, I have to extract label-values for each boundary and fish for the right one or store a corresponding (ideally sorted) idx to get it. But this is computationally really expensive.

```
    % the order in which regionprops objects are stored corresponds to the labels 
    obj_all_idx = zeros(numel(obj_all), 1);
    for k=1:length(obj_all)
        pixelList = obj_all(k).PixelIdxList;
        obj_all_idx(k) = obj_labelmap(pixelList(1));
    end; clear k;

    % the order in which obj_boundaries are stored does NOT correspond to the labels 
    obj_boundaries_idx = zeros(numel(obj_boundaries), 1);
    for k=1:length(obj_boundaries)
        boundary = obj_boundaries{k};
        col = boundary(1,2); row = boundary(1,1);
        obj_boundaries_idx(k) = obj_labelmap(row,col);
    end; clear k;
```

My question is: **Is there a good way to merge boundary, BoundingBox and Area properties of a region?** Am I overseeing something? Is there another way to generate these properties?

Answer (score 1):

you can apply `bwboundaries` directly on the `regionprops` output and that way no confusion is possible. It's the most straight forward to do that on `'Image'` property, but using `'PixelIdList'` is also possible:

```
% generate binary image
bw = imread('coins.png') > 100;
% get region props
props = regionprops(bw,{'Area','BoundingBox','Image','PixelIdxList'});
% split props to cells
C = struct2cell(props).';
regions = C(:,3);
bbox = C(:,2);
% extract boundaries from 'Image' property
B = cellfun(@(obj)bwboundaries(obj, 'noholes'),regions,'UniformOutput',0);
% add bounding box offset to boundary coordinates
B = cellfun(@(b,box) bsxfun(@plus,b{1},box([2 1]) - 0.5),B,bbox,'UniformOutput',0);
% assign boundaries cell to props struct
props(end).BWBoundary = [];
[props(:).BWBoundary] = deal(B{:});
% plot
imshow(bw);
hold on;
for ii = 1:numel(B)
    plot(B{ii}(:,2),B{ii}(:,1),'LineWidth',3)
    text(mean(B{ii}(:,2)),mean(B{ii}(:,1)),num2str(ii));
end
```

[image]